# Vectorized cell operation instead of for-loop

Tags: matlab, cell, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a part of my code dealing with cells but I don't manage to do it with the `funcell` function.

My problem is described below:

I have a variable named `pdif` of 4 cells, each containing 119 cells.
I want to find which is the good cell to choose, according to the parameters:

- `p1` (varying from 1 to 4)
- `p2` (varying from 1 to 119).

Thus if `p1 =2` and `p2=59`, the good cell is `pdif{2}{59}`.

In addition this work has to be repeated 2000 times.
As a consequence the 2000 parameters `p1` (and `p2`) are classed in the arrays `v1` (respectively `v2`)

Right now I use these lines codes:

```
goodcell=cell(2000,1); %intialization

for gg=1:2000

   goodcell{gg}=pdif{1,v1(gg)}{v2(gg),1};

end
```

It works but I would like to know if there is a way to write something like that:

```
goodcell=pdif{1,v1}{v2,1}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to switch to 2d-cells `pdif{v1,v2}`, is this possible? This would allow solutions like `pdif(sub2ind(size(pdif),v1,v2))`